# how to calculate the run time of a Traditional for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

How to calculate the run time for this traditional for loop :

```
for (i = 1; i < N; ++i) 
{ 
...statements that require exactly i operations... 
}
```

Please, anyone care to explain ?!!

Comment: i think it depends on what programming language you are using.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_clock.htm

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many times on SO...

Taken from [Complexity and Big-O Notation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html):

> The loop executes N times, so the sequence of statements also executes
>   N times. Since we assume the statements are O(1), the total time for
>   the for loop is N * O(1), which is O(N) overall.

So basically, it would be impossible to determine the time a for loop takes. There are manu factors for how much time something like that would take. For example:

1. Size of the array.
2. What are the objects you are looping through?
3. What are you doing inside the loop that could affect the complexity of time to complete each loop?

Etc., etc.

If you are looking to specifically calculate the time it takes for your `for loop` then you need to add something that determines the time between each loop, in whatever language you are attempting to write the code in.

By the way, you are starting your for loop at `index 1`, skipping the first `index 0`.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do for these kinds of question is to see how many iterations will the loop execute based on the input. For example,

```
for (i = 1; i < N; ++i);
```

This for loop will iterate `N - 1` times because `i` starts at 1 and the loop terminates when `i == N`.

Answer (score -1):

Google does not bite you:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm

Look first, then ask.